# How to find the scaffold views in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, scaffolding

I have created a domain class

person.php

```
class Person extends AppModel{
var $name='Person';
```

}

and controller

PersonsController.php

```
class PersonsController extends AppController{

var $scaffold;
```

}

As per this reference [Customizing Scaffold Views](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1105/Customizing-Scaffold-Views), I am not able to find the scaffold views in my application. Where to find the location of generated files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP does not generate files for app-specific scaffolds. It uses the default views in cake/libs/view/scaffolds. If you want to create your own views for scaffolds you have to create them in app/views/scaffolds either from scratch or by copying the default views there.